# how to make php regex preg_replace working

Tags: php, regex

I have to convert a string using `preg_replace`. Below is the string I need to convert

`@[ Test Career 12](career:235)@[ Testing11](business:2)@[ Username](user:1)some text`

I have created code to repalce the content, but it is not working. Please check the below code,

```
$Rtm = '@[ Test Career 12](career:235)@[ Testing11](business:2)@[ Username](user:1)some text';

if (preg_match("/@\[(.*?)\]\(user:(.*?)\)/", $Rtm, $match)) {
    $Rtm0 = preg_replace("/@\[(.*?)\]\(user:(.*?)\)/", '<a href="/en/main/profile_page_link/$2">$1</a>, ', $Rtm);

    $Rtm = rtrim($Rtm0, ', ');
}

if (preg_match("/@\[(.*?)\]\(business:(.*?)\)/", $Rtm, $match)) {
    $slug = "1";

    $Rtm01 = preg_replace("/@\[(.*?)\]\(business:(.*?)\)/", '<a href="/en/business/' . $slug . '/about">$1</a>, ', $Rtm);

    $Rtm = rtrim($Rtm01, ', ');
}

if (preg_match("/@\[(.*?)\]\(career:(.*?)\)/", $Rtm, $match)) {
    $slug = "2";

    $Rtm02 = preg_replace("/@\[(.*?)\]\(career:(.*?)\)/", '<a href="/en/main/' . $slug . '/about">$1</a>, ', $Rtm);

    $Rtm = rtrim($Rtm02, ', ');
}

echo $Rtm;
```

Output for the above code is,

`<a href="/en/main/profile_page_link/1"> Test Career 12](career:235)</a><a href="/en/business/1/about"> Testing11</a>, @[ Username, some text`

But my required output is,

`<a href="/en/main/2/about"> Test Career 12</a>, <a href="/en/business/1/about"> Testing11</a>, <a href="/en/main/profile_page_link/1"> Username</a> some text`

The given string is just a demo, the order may change as it is dynamic. But the structure is same.

How to get the required output. Is there any problem with my coding.

Comment: My suggestion is to test your regex here: https://regexr.com/ it shows all the steps, the groups and matchings

Comment: Use `@\[([^][]*?)\]` instead of `/@\[(.*?)\]`

Comment: Why do you have `, ` at the end of the replacement and then you remove it with `rtrim`?

Comment: @Toto thanks, it is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback) for this, capturing the text in `[]`, slug type (`user`, `career` or `business`) and value (for slug `user`) in groups and passing them through to the callback to form the URLs:

```
$Rtm = '@[ Test Career 12](career:235)@[ Testing11](business:2)@[ Username](user:1)some text';

$Rtm = preg_replace_callback('/@\[([^]]*)\]\(([a-z]+):([^)]*)\)/', function ($match) {
    switch($match[2]) {
        case 'user':
            return "<a href=\"/en/main/profile_page_link/$match[3]\">$match[1]</a>";
            break;
        case 'business':
            return "<a href=\"/en/business/1/about\">$match[1]</a>";
            break;
        case 'career':
            return "<a href=\"/en/main/2/about\">$match[1]</a>";
            break;
        default:
            return "";
            break;
    }
}, $Rtm);
echo $Rtm;
```

Output (for your input string):

```
<a href="/en/main/2/about"> Test Career 12</a><a href="/en/business/1/about"> Testing11</a><a href="/en/main/profile_page_link/1"> Username</a>some text
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tKTMo)

Answer (score 1):

Use `@\[([^][]*?)\]` instead of `@\[(.*?)\]` [Demo & explanation](https://regex101.com/r/g6VCkH/1).

Do the `rtrim` only once avfter all the replacements.

```php
$Rtm = '@[ Test Career 12](career:235)@[ Testing11](business:2)@[ Username](user:1)some text';

if (preg_match("/@\[([^][]*?)\]\(user:(.*?)\)/", $Rtm, $match)) {
    $Rtm = preg_replace("/@\[([^][]*?)\]\(user:(.*?)\)/", '<a href="/en/main/profile_page_link/$2">$1</a>, ', $Rtm);
}

if (preg_match("/@\[([^][]*?)\]\(business:(.*?)\)/", $Rtm, $match)) {
    $Rtm = preg_replace("/@\[([^][]*?)\]\(business:(.*?)\)/", '<a href="/en/business/$2/about">$1</a>, ', $Rtm);
}

if (preg_match("/@\[([^][]*?)\]\(career:(.*?)\)/", $Rtm, $match)) {
    $Rtm = preg_replace("/@\[([^][]*?)\]\(career:(.*?)\)/", '<a href="/en/main/$2/about">$1</a>, ', $Rtm);
}
$Rtm = rtrim($Rtm, ', ');

echo $Rtm;
```

Comment: if I change `$slug = $match[2]` and `$Rtm = '@[ Test Career 12](career:235)@[ Testing11](business:2)@[ Testing12](business:10)@[ Username](user:1)some text';`. Then it is not working.

Comment: Where does `$slug = $match[2]` come from?

Comment: To get the dynamic content

Comment: I think we can use `substr_replace($Rtm, ' ', strrpos($Rtm, ', '), 1)` to remove last occurance of comma.